# Cannot change the Ambiance theme in 17.10 with the Tweak tool

Tags: gnome, 17.10, themes, gtk, gnome-tweak-tool

Installing the Tweak tool, solving the problem of [installing and managing GNOME Shell extensions](https://askubuntu.com/q/75530/47206), and [enabling shell theme](https://askubuntu.com/q/545741/47206), I still cannot change the Applications theme, while shell and icons can be changed.

Clicking the Ambiance button gives no other options whatsoever, although I have installed a lot of gtk themes like Adapta.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that [a lot of problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w) with 17.10 can be solved by choosing upon login Xorg instead of [Wayland](https://www.maketecheasier.com/what-is-wayland/) as "display server" (log out, click your username, then the gear button, choose Xorg). Before this [not even Synaptic was working](https://askubuntu.com/q/963842/47206).

If one prefers Wayland, there are solutions under the linked question.